# How to access Flask API from Flask Frontend?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, wsgi

I am using Blueprints to create two separate modules, one for `api` and one for `website`. My APIs have a route prefix of `api`. Now, I am having a route in my website called `easy` and it will be fetching a JSON from a route in api called `easy` and it's route is `/api/easy`.
So, how can i call `/api/easy` from `/easy`.
I have tried using `requests` to call `http:localhost:5000/api/easy` and it works fine in development server but when I am deploying it on `Nginx` server, it fails probably because I am exposing port `80` there.
When I deploy my webapp on nginx, it show up perfectly just that route `/easy` throws Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what worked for me is I simply ended up calling the `api` function from the frontend rather than doing the POST requests. Obviously, it makes no sense creating backend routes for flask seperately when you are using Flask too in frontend. Simply, a seperate utility function would be fine.